# I want to pass the id using ajax call.. i have tried the following code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to pass the id of the button using ajax call ... and display the result into id called demo2 ...

```
<script>
function loadDoc2() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "get_coupon_code.php?offline_offer_id=" +this.id, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

<div id="demo2"></div>

<button id="111" onclick="loadDoc2()">Button 1</button>
<button id="222" onclick="loadDoc2()">Button 2</button>
<button id="333" onclick="loadDoc2()">Button 3</button>
```

Comment: pass `this.id` in method loadDoc2() like this `<button id="111" onclick="loadDoc2(this.id)">Button 1</button>` and get that id on javascript function like this : `loadDoc2(id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways
No 1.

```
<script>

 function loadDoc2(id) { //here is your id
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "get_coupon_code.php?offline_offer_id=" +this.id, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

<div id="demo2"></div>

<button id="111" onclick="loadDoc2("111")">Button 1</button>
<button id="222" onclick="loadDoc2("222")">Button 2</button>
<button id="333" onclick="loadDoc2("333")">Button 3</button>
```

No 2.

```
<script>
function loadDoc2() {
var Id = $(this).attr('id');  //here is your id
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "get_coupon_code.php?offline_offer_id=" +this.id, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

<div id="demo2"></div>

<button id="111" onclick="loadDoc2()">Button 1</button>
<button id="222" onclick="loadDoc2()">Button 2</button>
<button id="333" onclick="loadDoc2()">Button 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would had passed it on the function and use it as variable because "this" looks on the window scope.

```html
<script>
function loadDoc2(element) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "get_coupon_code.php?offline_offer_id=" +element.id, true);
  xhttp.send();
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = element.id + " clicked";
}
</script>

<div id="demo2"></div>

<button id="111" onclick="loadDoc2(this)">Button 1</button>
<button id="222" onclick="loadDoc2(this)">Button 2</button>
<button id="333" onclick="loadDoc2(this)">Button 3</button>
```